# How to map multiple Futures and pass them as arguments to a view using Play with Scala

Tags: scala, playframework

I think the title and the image below is enough to understand what I am trying to achieve here...
If it is not enough I will promptly edit this to add more details!

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`flatMap`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future@flatMap[S]%28f:T=%3Escala.concurrent.Future[S]%29%28implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext%29:scala.concurrent.Future[S]) instead of the first [`map`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future@map[S]%28f:T=%3ES%29%28implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext%29:scala.concurrent.Future[S]) :

```
repo.lookup(id) flatMap { album =>
  musicRepo.fromAlbum(id) map { musics =>
    Ok(views.html.albums.show(album, musics)
  }
}
```

Which you can replace by the following for comprehension :

```
for {
  album <- repo.lookup(id)
  musics <- musicRepo.fromAlbum(id)
} yield Ok(views.html.albums.show(album, musics)
```

You can also create the `Future`s before the for comprehension, this way the two calls can happen in parallel.

```
val fAlbum = repo.lookup(id)
val fMusics = musicRepo.fromAlbum(id)

for { album <- fAlbum; musics <- fMusics } 
yield Ok(views.html.albums.show(album, musics)
```

Comment: The second "for" approach is the best solution, this will wait for both Futures to resolve before passing it on to the view

Comment: Thanks! All of your solutions work! I've decided use the second "for" approach because of the advantages @Alex mentioned :)

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to return `Future[Result]`, you are returning `Future[Future[Result]` which causes your problem. Consider using flatMap

```
def show(id: Long) = Action.async {
  repo.lookup(id) flatMap { album =>
    musicRepo.findAlbum(id) map { musics =>
      Ok(views.html.albums.show(album, musics))
    }
  }
}
```